# Break items into columns evenly in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of cities names that is variable and I want to break it into 4 columns evenly. I have some solution but it looks overwhelmed and dirty. What's the best and simplest way to do it?

My solution is here:

```
{% set cities_in_column = cities|length/4|int %}
{% set step=0 %}
<div class="four columns">
    {% for city in cities|sort %}
        {% if step > cities_in_column %}
            {% set step = 0 %}
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
        {% endif %}
        <h5><a href="/city/{{ city.url }}">{{ city.name }}</a> <span style="float:right;">({{ city.users_count }})</span></h5>
        {% set step=step + 1 %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: The [`grouper` recipe from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the [`slices`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#slice) filter:

```
{% for column in cities | sort | slice(4) -%}
<div class="four columns">
    {%- for city in column -%}
    <h5><a href="/city/{{ city.url}}">{{ city.name }}</a>
    <span style="float:right;">({{ city.users_count }})</span></h5>
    {%- endfor -%}
</div>
{%- endfor %}
```

There is also a complement to [`slices`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#slice) called [`batch`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#batch) that provides runs of `n` (rather than splitting up the iterable into `n` groups).

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for CSS*:

```html
<ol style="column-count: 4;">
{% for city in cities|sort %}
    <li>
        <a href="/city/{{ city.url }}">{{ city.name }}</a> ({{ city.users_count }})
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

(*Be it `column-count`, `float`, `flex`, etc..)

Comment: how do you make css generate the required html?  It needs to be done in the template

Comment: @cstrutton You only need the (unbroken) items in the HTML, which is what the for loop does in the example provided in my answer. The other approaches here use Django's template language, unnecessarily, to break the items into four columns as requested, but CSS alone can do this, and with much less code and effort.